# Cakephp delete not working for multiple DB connect

Tags: cakephp

I am using cakephp 2.4 , am working on a project which uses two db connections based on the user logged in. while accessing the second DB and Retrieve data it is working fine, but when i delete record in the second DB table record its throw error as ..

```
Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected
```

Can anyone help on this ...

this is my DB connect code

```
$this->default['host'] = 'localhost';
$this->default['login'] = 'xxxxxx';
$this->default['password'] = 'xxxx';
$this->default['database'] = 'xxxxx';
$this->default['prefix'] = 'xxxx_';
if(!empty($_SESSION['subsites'])){
$this->test['host'] = 'localhost';
$this->test['login'] = 'xxxx';
$this->test['password'] = 'xxxxx';
$this->test['database'] = 'ccxxxx';
$this->test['prefix'] = 'xxxx'.'_';
}
```

then we used $useDBconfig ='test'; in model

Comment: can you paste the code that handles the database switch?

Answer (score 1):

Define multiple database configuration in app/config/database.php as

```
   public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'db1',
    'prefix' => '',
    //'encoding' => 'utf8',
);

public $subSites = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'db2',
    'prefix' => '',
    //'encoding' => 'utf8',
);
```

Now when you want to switch to subSites  config just write following code:

```
$this->Model->useDbConfig = $subSites;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  **$useDbConfig** Attribute inside your Model.

```
 class Example extends AppModel {
    public $useDbConfig = 'user';
}
```

Inside your Controller, simply use:

```
 $this->ModelName->useDbConfig = 'user';
```

for More Details, please click on http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html